# Good and pythonic way to filter list of dictionaries with regular expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, dictionary

So let's say I have a list/tuple like this.

```
dic = ({name: 'Kan',number: '2ABC345', year: '2000'}, 
 {name: 'Jhon',number: '2TTC345', year: '2001'},
 {name: 'Louise',number: '2ABC366', year: '2001'},
 {name: 'Kevin',number: '2ABY000', year: '2002'})
```

How can I use filters and regular expressions on this list?
I was thinking of something like this, but I can't seem to correct the code.

```
 def func(dic, expression, keysection):
    r = re.compile(dic)
    x = list(filter(lambda x: r.findall(rexpression) in x[keysection], dic))
    print(x)
```

So let's say I want the year 2000 I would do something like this,

```
func(dic, 2000, 'year')
>>> [{name: 'Kan',number: '2ABC345', year: 2000}]
```

or the first letter in name be a k,

```
func(dic, '^K', 'name')
>>> [ {name: 'Kan',number: '2ABC345', year: 2000}, {name: 'Kevin',number: '2ABY000', year: 2002}]
```

or to see if the number starts with 2 and has 7 numbers,

```
func(dic, '2\d{7}', 'number')
>>> [ {name: 'Kan',number: '2ABC345', year: 2000}, {name: 'Jhon',number: '2TTC345', year: 2001},{name: 'Louise',number: '2ABC366', year: 2001}, {name: 'Kevin',number: '2ABY000', year: 2002} ]
```

The thing is, I'm new to regular expression, and I'm not sure if the code above is right and what is the best and most pythonic way to use regular expression filters.

Comment: All functionality you're trying to implement already exist in `filter()`. You pass callable which check condition, it's the most "pythonic" way.

Comment: yes but i don't know how to use it with regular expression

Comment: `filter(lambda d: re.match(r'2\d{6}', d['number']), dic)`

Comment: All your keys in `dic` have to be strings. Otherwise you would be calling for the variable `name`, for example.

Comment: dind't understand were u talking about the year key if so it would also be in strings

Comment: Yes, you would have to put all the keys in quotes: `{name: 'Kan',number: '2ABC345', year: '2000'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start from a remark that regular expressions operate on **strings**.
So it is good that you corrected your *dic* so that each dictionary
contains strings (initially *year* was a number).

The first correction that you should made is that `re.compile(dic)`
is wrong.
You can compile a **pattern**, not the dictionary.

And since you execute your pattern **once** only, there is no need
to compile it in advance. It is simpler when you use just the *pattern*
argument (a string).

Your function can be:

```
def func(dic, pat, key):
    return list(filter(lambda x: re.search(pat, x[key]), dic))
```

When you want just to print what has been found, it is enough that the
function returns the finding and when you call the function the
result will be printed.

Try `func(dic, '2000', 'year')` and `func(dic, '^K', 'name')`.
It should print just what you want.

But an attempt to run `func(dic, '2\d{7}', 'number')` will return *[]*
(an empty list), since no *number* in your data sample contains *2*
followed by 7 digits.

But you can e.g. run `func(dic, '2A[A-Z]{2}', 'number')`, i.e. find
dictionaries with *number* containing:

- *'2A'*,
- and then 2 letters.

This time you will get:

```
[{'name': 'Kan', 'number': '2ABC345', 'year': '2000'},
 {'name': 'Louise', 'number': '2ABC366', 'year': '2001'},
 {'name': 'Kevin', 'number': '2ABY000', 'year': '2002'}]
```

## Edit

If you have some elements of your dictionaries **other** that strings,
you can convert them to a string in your function. Change your function to:

```
def func(dic, pat, key):
    return list(filter(lambda x: re.search(pat, str(x[key])), dic))
```

and it will work also on non-string elements in your source dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't try to make a function with all of these responsibilities. It will make testing extremely difficult. Instead I would use the simplest list comprehensions possible for each case:

```
import re

dic = (
    {"name": "Kan",    "number": "2ABC345", "year": 2000},
    {"name": "Jhon",   "number": "2TTC345", "year": 2001},
    {"name": "Louise", "number": "2ABC366", "year": 2001},
    {"name": "Kevin",  "number": "2ABY000", "year": 2002},
)


# So let's say I want the year 2000
year_2000 = [d for d in dic if d["year"] == 2000]

# or the first letter in name be a k
name_k = [d for d in dic if d["name"].startswith("K")]

# or to see if the number starts with 2 and has 7 numbers
starts_2_digits_7 = [d for d in dic if re.match(r"^2\d{6}$", d["number"])]
```

Comment: I understand but I'm using a CSV file which is where the list of dic comes from with more than 1000 keys I wanted an efficient function that could help me instead of doing a few hundred lists comprehensions

Comment: @jhonny `large csv + filtering + efficiency == pandas`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a function for it. Regular expressions have to be readable. Lambda does the job.

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: x['year'] == 2000, dic)))

# Output:
[{'name': 'Kan', 'number': '2ABC345', 'year': 2000}]

print(list(filter(lambda x: x['name'][0] == 'K', dic)))

# Output:
[{'name': 'Kan', 'number': '2ABC345', 'year': 2000},
 {'name': 'Kevin', 'number': '2ABY000', 'year': 2002}]

print(list(filter(lambda x: x['number'][0] == '2' and len(x['number']) == 7, dic)))

# Output:
[{'name': 'Kan', 'number': '2ABC345', 'year': 2000},
 {'name': 'Jhon', 'number': '2TTC345', 'year': 2001},
 {'name': 'Louise', 'number': '2ABC366', 'year': 2001},
 {'name': 'Kevin', 'number': '2ABY000', 'year': 2002}]
```

But I really recommend using pandas for this.